# Building binutils-2.31.1: No linker produced

Tags: gcc, linker, binutils

As part of trying to build a gcc 8.2 cross-compiler (targeting ia64-hp-hpux11.31), I'm running into problems building binutils 2.31.1. The build actually seems to complete just fine. I end with a bunch of binaries (ar, objdump, strings, etc.), but some important ones like `as` and `ld` are missing. I think I configured binutils properly, explicitely enabling ld and disabling gold: `../binutils-2.31.1/configure --target=ia64-hp-hpux11.31 --enable-ld=yes --enable-gold=no`.

I scanned through the stdout + stderr output of the entire build process, but didn't find any hints. The only suspicous thing is that `configure` outputs: `checking whether we are cross compiling... no`. Shouldn't that say yes, since I'm building for cross compilation? If my understanding of how `--build`, `--host` and `--target` work is correct, shouldn't that imply cross compilation?

I should note this is my first time trying to build a cross-compiler. I should also note that my Linux "machine" is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS under the Windows Subsystem for Linux, perhaps this has something to do with it.

---

[My config.log](https://gist.github.com/Lisoph/155d55589d1b5eb5303b0e48bc234173)

Comment: Could you upload the config.log somewhere?

Comment: Sure, [here it is](https://gist.github.com/Lisoph/155d55589d1b5eb5303b0e48bc234173).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `configure` script at line 3744:

```
  ia64*-**-hpux*)
    # No ld support yet.
    noconfigdirs="$noconfigdirs gdb libgui itcl ld"
    ;;
```

That causes the `ld` directory to be skipped during the build.

You should have an assembler though, built as `gas/as-new` (after `make install` that will get installed as `ia64-hp-hpux11.31-as`).

Comment: Thank you, binutils indeed does not support ld and other tools for HP-UX, it seems. At least for cross compilation. I guess I'll have to use the native binaries for the unsupported tools.